# Add space between each character after it is multiplied n times in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So basically we have to enter 2 lists. Then each of the list elements is added to its corresponding element (as shown in the example below) to create a sum list. Then we take a string and take the first character of the string. We then multiply the character with the numbers from the sum list. The problem I'm having is that I want to add a space every time the character is repeated (as shown below).

This is my code:

```
l1 = [i for i in eval(input("Enter a list: "))]
l2 = [i for i in eval(input("Enter another list: "))]
symbol = input("Enter symbol: ")


summation = []
for (i1, i2) in zip(l1, l2):
    summation.append(i1+i2)

i = 0
while i < len(summation):
    print(summation[i] , symbol[0]*summation[i])
    i += 1
```

This is how my output looks:

```
Enter a list: 1,2,3
Enter another list: 1,2,3
Enter symbol: hello world
2 hh
4 hhhh
6 hhhhhh
```

This is how I want my output to look:

```
Enter a list: 1,2,3
Enter another list: 1,2,3
Enter symbol: hello world
2 h h
4 h h h h
6 h h h h h h
```

Can someone please help me? It might be a stupid question but I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: I suspect that all you need is the operation `' '.join(char_list)`, where  you fill in the argument with the characters you want separated.

Comment: Please convert images to code snippets

Comment: @TedBrownlow I have added the code snippets

Comment: @Prune I did try adding that, but it only separates the first or last character depending on where I add ' '.join(symbol)

Comment: Hint: `5 * 'x'` is `'xxxxx'` and `5 * 'x '` is `'x x x x x '`. Also, `' '.join('xxx')` is `'x x x'`.

Comment: @zvone I understand that. All I want to know is how to add that to a user input character/string.

Comment: zvone just showed you how to add it to an arbitrary string.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
symbol[0]*summation[i]
```

with

```
(symbol[0] + " ")*summation[i]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this!

Comment: @Shahnawazyasser I would instead recommend `" ".join(symbol[0] * summation[i])`, since this will not result in trailing whitespace.